# Jasperviewer in Netbeans: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java

When i execute the project in Netbeans 6.5, while viewing the reports (jasper reports) jasperviewer opens, but not fully. and in output window it throws exception like this:

```
Exception occurred during event dispatching:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.awt.image.DataBufferByte.<init>(DataBufferByte.java:58)
    at java.awt.image.ComponentSampleModel.createDataBuffer(ComponentSampleModel.java:397)
    at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Raster.java:938)
    at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createBufferedImage(ImageTypeSpecifier.java:1169)
    at javax.imageio.ImageReader.getDestination(ImageReader.java:2879)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:943)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:915)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1422)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1326)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRJdk14ImageReader.readImage(JRJdk14ImageReader.java:58)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.loadImage(JRImageLoader.java:248)
    ....
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to post the entire stacktrace?

Answer (score 3):

Give yourself more heap space:

```
java -Xmx512m ...
```

for 512M and so on.

Netbeans will give you somewhere an option to specify VM parameters (of which -Xmx is one that affects memory usage).

Another piece of advice: if you are using the bean shell compiler for Jasper Reports, don't. It's a huge memory hog and it's slow. Make sure you use the JDT compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a JVM argument to your Project runtime settings to increase the amount of available heap space; e.g.

```
-mx256M
```

... will increase your available heap to 256 Megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

For a permanent solution, try profiling your application with a profiler. Check this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap-s)

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [visualgc](http://java.sun.com/performance/jvmstat/visualgc.html) to see what is happening when I run out of memory. VisualGC will help you see which part of memory is actually the problem.

Here is a snippet from a question on how to set memory parameters in netbeans.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Java/Q_21039388.html

```
It's been a while since I used netbeans but there is a file that is called ide.cfg

Here you can edit the line:
        -J-Xverify:none -J-Xms24m -J-Xmx96m

and make the -J-Xmx parameter to be 128 Mb like this:

        -J-Xverify:none -J-Xms24m -J-Xmx128m

On a more gerneral note: It's probably more efficient to look at the memory usage of your app. If it's doing this during development your are going to have fun with this app in production...
```